# In Java, how to force an Exception to "bubble up"?

Tags: java, exception

I have a method that throws an Exception, which calls a method which throws an Exception, etc etc. So several methods that "throw Exception" are daisy-chained.
The first method that calls the submethod, puts that submethod in a try-catch block that catches any `Exception` that gets thrown inside that call. IN THEORY. In practice, no Exception is being caught by that try-catch block. Is there a way to remedy that?

Here is the code:

```
          try {
                CSVSingleton.tryToReadBothFiles(FILE1_PATH, FILE2_PATH);

                } catch (Exception e) { // THIS BLOCK NEVER GETS ENTERED BY THE PATH O EXECUTION
System.out.println("There was an exception reading from at least one of the files. Exiting.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
```

here is the method from the CSVSingleton class:

```
public static void tryToReadBothFiles(String filePath1, String filePath2) throws Exception {

        file1 = new CSVFileForDwellTime1(filePath1);
        file2 = new CSVFileForDwellTime2(filePath2);
    }
```

And here is code from the CSVFileForDwellTime1 class:

```
public CSVFileForDwellTime1(String filePath) throws Exception {
        super(filePath);
    }
```

and then here is the code that actually throws an original FileNotFoundException:

```
public GenericCSVFile(String filePath) throws Exception{
        this.filePath = filePath;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
            csvReader = new CSVReader(
                    fileReader);
            header = getActualHeaderNames();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not read file with name: " + filePath);
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My guess is that the FileNotFoundException in the last method is caught by the catch block and so doesn't "bubble up". But is there a way to force it to bubble up?

Comment: simply call `throw e` or `throw new MyCustomException("your custom error message")` in `catch (FileNotFoundException e)` block.

Comment: Yes: don't catch it. Catching it is precisely what prevents it from being thrown. And don't use `throws Exception`. Declare the precise exception type(s) that can be thrown by the method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Immediate answer:**

Your thought is exactly right,

```
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
        csvReader = new CSVReader(
                fileReader);
        header = getActualHeaderNames();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not read file with name: " + filePath);
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This suppresses the exception
Either remove the `try-catch` block (desired unless you can actually do something with the exception)or re-throw it within the `catch` block.

***Explanation***

Generally with `checked` exceptions like this you have 2 options

1. Catch the exception and do something to remedy the exception
2. Throw the exception to the caller

What you have done here falls into the 1st category except that you have not done anything useful in the `catch` block (printing to console is rarely useful in this case because the exception message itself normally has enough information to see what has gone wrong)

The 2nd category is achieved either by not using a `try-catch` block and thus adding `throws FileNotFoundException` to the method signature. Alternatively explicitly `throw` the exception that you caught using:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    //do something
    throw e;
}
```

however in this case if `do something` isn't worthwhile you have unnecessarily caught something just to throw it on.

You can think of it like this:

```
Alice throws a ball to Charlie
Bob intercepts the ball
Bob then looks at the ball and then throws it to Charlie
```

***Bonus Points***

When you know the exception that could occur make sure to actually `catch` or `throw` that exception and not a parent of that exception.
Take the following method signatures for example:

```
public String method1() throws Exception

public String method2() throws FileNotFoundException
```

Here `method2` clearly tells the caller what could happen and can help then figure out why the exception is being called (without having to read through the code or experience the error).

Secondly other exceptions can occur and you are potentially catching the wrong exception, take the following example:

```
try{
    fileReader = new FileReader(filePath); //could potentially throw FileNotFoundException
    fileReader = null; //woops
    csvReader = new CSVReader(fileReader); //throws NullPointerException but the compiler will not know this 
    //....other stuff....//
}
catch(Exception e){
    // the compiler told me that a FileNotFoundException can occur so i assume that is the reason the catch has executed
    System.err.println("You have entered an invalid filename");
    //doing anything here that would fix a FileNotFoundException is pointless because that is not the exception that occured
}
```

Comment: he could have used finally { } for doing the System.err.println() and so java would have propagated the exception on it's own right?

Comment: @FernandoGabrieli, that would cause the error to always be printed, even when no error occurred.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `throw` in the catch clause.

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Could not read file with name: " + filePath);
    // Continue up, Mr. Exception!
    throw e;
}
```

Alternatively, wrap the exception as appropriate (since an IOException is checked this handy here) - this is called a [Chained Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html). Then, depending on what is thrown, the `throws Exception` can be removed from the method signature.

```
throw new RuntimeException("Could not read file: " + filePath, e);
```

Comment: This is however considered as a bad practice: it loses the actual place where the original exception was thrown. Wrapping it into another exception would be cleaner. Not catching the exception in the first place would be even cleaner in this case.

Comment: Why would you opt to remove useful information like the fact that your method may `throw an exception`

Comment: @RossBille Because I don't believe in checked exceptions - it then forces the entire upward chain to deal with "an exception" or itself annotate with throws. (C# dropped this idea, and I've never missed it.)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to catch it, then don't. Alternatively, you can just throw it again with a `throw`-statement. You can also throw a new Exception of any class you like. You should only catch an Exception at a level where you can react to it properly. As you found out, catching it at that low level is not helpful, so do not catch it there.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you just need to add `throw e` right after `System.out.println("Could not read file with name: " + filePath);` and the exception will propagate up to the first method.

However, this would not be a clean way to handle the exception, because in this case all you'd be doing is printing an error message at the cost of changing the location of the original `FileNotFoundException`. Ideally, when you need to inspect an exception stacktrace, you expect a line of code throwing an exception to be the *actual* line that really caused the exception.

The `throws Exception` in the method declaration should be considered part of the contract of the method, i.e. it describes *a possible behavior of the method*. You should always ask yourself: Does it make sense for a `FileNotFoundException` to be specified as a possible exceptional behavior for the method/constructor I'm writing? In other words, do I want to make the caller of my method aware of this exception and leave it to the caller to deal with it? If the answer is yes (and in this case I would say it makes sense), then avoid wrapping the code in a `try-catch` block. If no, then your `catch` block should be responsible for dealing with the exception itself. In this specific example IMO there is not much you can do in the `catch` statement, so just remove the `try-catch`.

As mentioned by others, you should declare the ***most specific*** exception in the method signature (`throws FileNotFoundException` instead of `throws Exception`).

Answer (score 1):

You can rethrow the exception once you catch it, for callees further up the stack to handle. You can change what exception it is too if a new type of exception makes more sense at a higher level.

```
catch (SomeSpecificException e)
{
    some code here
    throw new AMoreBroadException("I really need the callee to handle this too");
}
```